# Google Maps API & Internet Explorer 8/9

Tags: internet-explorer, api, google-maps, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

For some reason a Google Map via the Javascript API is not loading correctly in Internet Explorer.

It displays in Google Chrome & Firefox absolutely fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>Google Maps</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/> 
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
        <link href="https://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <style>
            #map_canvas {font: 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#3B3B3B; height:400px; width: 700px;}
            .text {text-align:center; color:#3B3B3B;}
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
          var geocoder;
          var map;

          function initialize() {
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
            var myOptions = {
              zoom: 15,
              center: latlng,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
          }

          function codeAddress() {
            var address = '50 Bond Street, London';
            geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
              if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map, 
                    position: results[0].geometry.location
                });
              } else {
            //Not Found
              }
            });
          }
        </script> 
        <script type="text/javascript">
            initialize(); 
            codeAddress();
        </script>
    </head> 
    <body onload="initialize(); codeAddress();"> 
        <div id="map_canvas"></div> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

Strangely if I put a onmouseover on the Body and call the functions it seems to start working again? But it obviously reloads the maps each time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you are calling your functions from body onload event. Maybe the scripts are not loaded properly at that time?

Try loading the api this way. You get to load the API ascynchronously and specify a callback function to initialize content.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload=%7Bmodules%3A%5B%7Bname%3A%22maps%22%2Cversion%3A3%2Cother_params%3A%22sensor%3Dfalse%22%7D%5D%7D"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: myLatlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
  }

  google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
</script>
```

[edit: previous solution did not work. Real solution is in the comments, I simply put it here]

Comment: Hi Maxime, That comes back with an error. I think it's because it cannot append the tag until after the body has loaded. It comes back with a NULL error.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that this is being called from another page that has an iFrame. I think this might be behind the issue.

Comment: The fact that if you bind your functions on a mouseover event that happens after page load makes it all work is what makes me think the scripts are not loaded properly on IE onload event. Loading the API async should fix the issue since you can provide a callback method to initialize your components. I'm using this method to load maps in my projects [Autoload](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/commonloader/autoload.html)